# character set configuration in php.ini file

Tags: php, character-encoding

I was trying to change default character set in php.ini file by following a configuration setting in an online article, but the two seems to contradict. Would like to confirm which is correct among the two below:

```
default_charset = "UTF-8"
```

or

```
default_charset = UTF-8
```

w/ or w/o double quotation(") marks.

Comment: IIRC both are ok (you can test them by setting them, and verifying the result in the `content-type` header returned by the server)

Answer (score 1):

> in php.ini

```
default_charset = "utf-8"
```

> or run time

```
ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');
```

> in php file

```
header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

Comment: pretty the same I guess!